# Replace character inside the htmlText

Tags: regex, actionscript-3, apache-flex, html, htmltext

I have a htmlText with this normal content:

`<TEXTFORMAT LEADING="2"><P ALIGN="LEFT"><FONT>...</FONT></P></TEXTFORMAT>`

And user can customize my textFeild, so it would happen to have many `<p>` tags, inside this htmlText... How can I replace all these `<p>` tags to `<span>` ?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
htmlText.replace(/<(\/?)p([^>]*)>/gi, "<$1span$2>");
```

Comment: tanx @Kodiak for your respond! But are you sure about your reg. exp. pattern?!

Comment: Sorry I forgot to escape the slash :)

Comment: Yep! tanq ;) BTW, it still not working. I just tarce the line like this: `trace(htmlText.replace(/<(\/?)p >/g, "<$1span>"));` but still no change :(

Comment: Aha! I Changed the `/g` to `/gi` @Kodiak and it kinda works now, but it just changes the `</p>` to `</span>` and not the `<P ALIGN="LEFT">` to `<SPAN ALIGN="LEFT">`... How can I make that too?